# azure sql limit dtu resources per operation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Sadly last week azure transfer one database from web tier to s1 tier. I manually increase the tier to s2. worked hard to change some stuff in the system so the dtu wont reach 100%.

Now i have new situation - i get background stuff that run and doing stuff in the db like delete etc. the problem is that the background stuff consume 100 percent dtu and my website start getting errors.

my question is: is there a way to tell the sql per query/operation to consume max of X dtu? for example i want to create an index and again when i do the operation my dtu raise to 100 and it stayed there allot of time - guess its a big index to build - so again im stuck and i cancel the query because i dont want my end users to suffer lags.

all those issue didnt exists in the web tier and everything worked smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very nice suggestion,unfortunately limiting  a particular query or operation to consume limited DTU is not possible ..may be in future versions they might bring resource governor like tools

Closest thing i can think  of limiting DTU for a query is set to

```
Option (MAXDOP 1)
```

Query may go in Parallel and consume more resources for each thread ,so limiting MAXDOP will help in limiting DTU with some caveats

Comment: So what you saying at the moment i cant create an index to better perform my application without hurting my end users

Comment: why you need to create index again and again,there might be a better way of doing this..What  i am saying is you can't restrict DTU for a query or operarion,use maxdop option which will ensure this will consume less resources with some caveats

Comment: You have the option to go higher in the performance level for the time it takes to create the index. You are billed per hour.